# Функция возвращающая количество месяцев, дней, недель, часов в секундах

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, рекурсия, timestamp

Мне нужна функция, которая принимает количество секунд и возвращает строку формата

> ```
> N г. N мес. N нед. N д. N ч.
> ```

```
year = 31536000
month = 2592000
week = 604800
day = 86400
hour = 3600


from math import floor


def parse_time(time_s):
    if time_s == 0:
        return None
    if time_s < hour:
        return 'меньше часа'
    if time_s >= year:
        return '{} г. '.format(floor(time_s / year)) + parse_time(time_s % year)
    if time_s >= month:
        return '{} мес. '.format(floor(time_s / month)) + parse_time(time_s % month)
    elif time_s >= week:
        return '{} нед. '.format(floor(time_s / week)) + parse_time(time_s % week)
    elif time_s >= day:
        return '{} д. '.format(floor(time_s / day)) + parse_time(time_s % day)
    else:
        return '{} ч.'.format(floor(time_s / hour))
```

Я написал такую функцию, но немного сомневаюсь в её корректности.

`year, month, week, day, hour` – колличество секунд.

Примеры запуска:

```
print(parse_time(2827567.5759670734))  # 1 мес. 2 д. 17 ч.
print(parse_time(269649.6857390404))   # 3 д. 2 ч.
```

Comment: Функция принимает `time_s`, но в коде уже используются `hour`, `year` и т.д. Куда-то потерялись их определения :)

Comment: так они глобальные, используются в других функциях. могу добавить их в вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос пару примеров входных данных в `parse_time`, чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть как нужно :) А так навскидку, глобальные переменные тут не нужны. Рекурсия тоже, хотя ее использование у вас выглядит интересно. Можно попробовать секунды перевести в дату и через форматирование даты вывести: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: добавил примеры входных данных

Comment: Т.е. если у нас, например, год не наберется в дате, то не будем возвращать 0: `0 г. 1 мес. 1 нед. 1 д. 1 ч.`?

Comment: Нет, возвращаем только то, что наберется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79016/discussion-between-pinguin-and-gil9red).

Comment: как можно считать месяцы без точки отсчета? дней же 28-31. год тоже високосный или нет?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к предыдущему вопросу. Откуда взялись year = 31536000
month = 2592000. Не даром таких простых и частых функций перевода в Datatime нет -   в году может быть 31 536 000 секунд или 31 622 400  если он високосный. А в месяце - 2419200, 2505600, 2592000 или 2 678 400. За три года существования вопроса этого никто не заметил?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно без рекурсии сделать:

```
def parse_time(time_s):
    year = 31536000
    month = 2592000
    week = 604800
    day = 86400
    hour = 3600

    if time_s == 0:
        return None

    if time_s < hour:
        return 'меньше часа'

    result = ''

    if time_s >= year:
        result += '{} г. '.format(int(time_s / year))
        time_s %= year

    if time_s >= month:
        result += '{} мес. '.format(int(time_s / month))
        time_s %= month

    if time_s >= week:
        result += '{} нед. '.format(int(time_s / week))
        time_s %= week

    if time_s >= day:
        result += '{} д. '.format(int(time_s / day))
        time_s %= day

    if time_s >= hour:
        result += '{} ч.'.format(int(time_s / hour))

    return result
```

Как видно, алгоритм повторяется, и меняется только пара элементов в нем, а значит это легко представить в цикле:

```
def parse_time(time_s):
    items = [
        (31536000, '{} г. '),
        (2592000, '{} мес. '),
        (604800, '{} нед. '),
        (86400, '{} д. '),
        (3600, '{} ч.'),
    ]
    
    if time_s == 0:
        return None

    if time_s < 3600:
        return 'меньше часа'

    result = ''

    for value, fmt in items:
        if time_s >= value:
            result += fmt.format(int(time_s / value))
            time_s %= value

    return result
```

Пример:

```
print(parse_time(2827567.5759670734))  # 1 мес. 2 д. 17 ч.
assert parse_time(2827567.5759670734) == "1 мес. 2 д. 17 ч."

print(parse_time(269649.6857390404))   # 3 д. 2 ч.
assert parse_time(269649.6857390404) == "3 д. 2 ч."
```

---

**PS.** `floor` можно заменить на `int`. [Разница между floor и int проявится на отрицательных числах](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31036156/5909792).

Answer (score 1):

Для простоты можно разделить чистые вычисления и форматирование (ввод/вывод). К примеру, можно реализовать отдельно функцию, которая разделяет секунды на отдельные единицы времени (годы, дни, часы, итд):

```
def broken_down_time(
    seconds,
    units=[
        ("year", 31536000),
        ("month", 2592000),
        ("week", 604800),
        ("day", 86400),
        ("hour", 3600),
    ],
):
    t = {}
    for unit, value in units:
        if seconds >= value:
            t[unit], seconds = divmod(seconds, value)
    return t
```

Пример:

```
>>> broken_down_time(2827567)
{'month': 1, 'day': 2, 'hour': 17}
>>> broken_down_time(269649)
{'day': 3, 'hour': 2}
```

От функции, которая форматирует полученное время:

```
def format_time(
    t,
    units=[
        ("year", "г."),
        ("month", "мес."),
        ("week", "нед."),
        ("day", "д."),
        ("hour", "ч."),
    ],
):
    return " ".join(f"{t[unit]} {unit_ru}" for unit, unit_ru in units if unit in t)
```

Пример:

```
>>> format_time(broken_down_time(seconds=2827567))
'1 мес. 2 д. 17 ч.'
```

Здесь float->int преобразование до вызова функций сделано.

Чтобы не дублировать набор единиц времени, можно класс создать, который принимает единицы времени, секунды и позволяет обращаться к отдельным компонентам, выводить локализованное текстовое представление (то есть объединяет приведённые функции). К примеру, [как это `pendulum.interval` делает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43037117/4279).